# Python worksheet.write concatenate 2 columns into 1

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I have 2 columns:

- Date
- User

I've trying to concat both column to get in the end only one column like this:

- Date / User

but I'm not sure how to do this when working with Python worksheet.write

Anyone here have experience with this class?

for sure, should be a simple solution for a user that already worked with this class

```
import xlsxwriter

worksheet.write('A' + str(x), unicode(Date , 'utf-8'), headerBorderFormat)
worksheet.write('B' + str(x), unicode(Username, 'utf-8'), headerBorderFormat)
worksheet.write('C' + str(x), unicode(Date + ' / ' + Username, 'utf-8'), headerBorderFormat)

# get and display one row at a time.
for row in details:
    x += 1
    worksheet.write('A' + str(x), row[0], dateFormat)
    worksheet.write('B' + str(x), row[1], tableDataFormat)
    #here I have to concat row[0] + ' / ' + row[1]


workbook.close()
```

Comment: What kind of object is your `worksheet`? you have neither provided the import nor set a tag for the library you use. Sorry it's not obvious for me.

Comment: If I had to guess, I would say try:
`unicode(Date) + ' / ' + unicode(Username, 'utf-8')` instead of
`unicode(Date + ' / ' + Username, 'utf-8')`

Comment: unicode(Date + ' / ' + Username, 'utf-8') -> WORK but its concat only column headers, what I need is to concat all columns values, samething like row[0]+ ' / ' + row[1]

Comment: change the values in the for loop accordingly, I will put example code in an answer.

Comment: I don't think that it's possible to have multiple formats like `dateFormat` and `tableDataFormat` given for one cell. You maybe have to cast your data to strings first.

Comment: Another minor tip, if your x is just the index (0 before the loop) you can define it directly in the for loop using `for x, row in enumerate(details):` it just saves two lines of code, but it's a handy shortcut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `row`s first element is a datetime object and the second a string something like this could work, when you provide the wanted format for the date (see https://strftime.org/):

```py
# single column header:
col_name = unicode(Date , 'utf-8') + ' / ' + unicode(Username, 'utf-8')
worksheet.write('A' + str(x), col_name, headerBorderFormat)

# get and display one row at a time.
for row in details:
    x += 1
    format = '%Y%m%d'
    cell_content = row[0].strftime(format) + ' / ' + row[1]
    worksheet.write('A' + str(x), cell_content, tableDataFormat)
```

Comment: yes sarbot, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for your help